# Empty wallet after making a Bitcoin purchase

Tags: wallet

I am new to Bitcoin and purchased a small amount some months ago and it does not show in my wallet even after finishing syncing. How to I find my bitcoins and get them to show in my wallet?

Comment: When you bought them, where did they go? Were they in your wallet and you've since changed computers or reinstalled your operating system?

Comment: Because you mention "syncing", can we assume you are referring to the Bitcoin-Qt client?

Comment: When I bought them I thought I sent them to my wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the address in [blockchain.info](http://www.blockchain.info) and see where the funds have gone.

Comment: Where do I find the address or how do I get to blockchain.info??

Comment: @user3749 Enter http://blockchain.info/ in your browser URL bar, press enter, type the Bitcoin address you entered when you purchased into the search bar at the upper right.